# React does not recognize the `getJson` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://github.com/itachiRedhair/react-dropzone-csv-to-json

using this library, I got this error.

> index.js:1452 Warning: React does not recognize the `getJson` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `getjson` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

what I imported is below like this,,,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import csv from "csvtojson";

export default class ModifiedDropZone extends Component {
  state = {
    files: []
  };

  onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
    this.setState({
      files: acceptedFiles
    });

    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        const fileAsBinaryString = reader.result;

        csv({
          noheader: true,
          output: "json"
        })
          .fromString(fileAsBinaryString)
          .then(csvRows => {
            const toJson = [];
            csvRows.forEach((aCsvRow, i) => {
              if (i !== 0) {
                const builtObject = {};

                Object.keys(aCsvRow).forEach(aKey => {
                  const valueToAddInBuiltObject = aCsvRow[aKey];
                  const keyToAddInBuiltObject = csvRows[0][aKey];
                  builtObject[keyToAddInBuiltObject] = valueToAddInBuiltObject;
                });

                toJson.push(builtObject);
              }
            });

            const { getJson } = this.props;
            getJson(toJson);
          });
      };

      reader.onabort = () => console.log("file reading was aborted");
      reader.onerror = () => console.log("file reading has failed");

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} {...this.props}>
        {children}
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
}
```

and use this component like this,,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { DropZone } from "../lib";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    jsonResult: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 640, margin: "15px auto" }}>
        <div>
          <DropZone
            getJson={jsonResult => {
              this.setState({ jsonResult });
            }}
          >
            <p>Add a file and see for yourself</p>
          </DropZone>
          {this.state.jsonResult ? (
            <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.jsonResult)}</div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in my opinion, The problem is,  react doesn't know getJson in DropZone, but I have no idea what can be wrong here. this is my first react trial, so I don't know how to deal with it.

Any ideas? You can see this warning, after yarn install and just yarn start

Comment: try `import DropZone from "../lib";`

Comment: @ic3b3rg it's not works, either...

Comment: it looks like you're missing the file name in the import

Comment: @ic3b3rg  but I can use this component well only got error... did you installed this?

Comment: No I haven't installed it. The import looks wrong to me. Your file has a default export, so you have to use the default import (not a named import). Also, `lib` is a most likely a folder, not a file name.

Comment: @ic3b3rg I edited `from "../lib/DropZone.jsx";` like this. but it not works. error just same

Comment: @mjwills the top part in this question, I wrote **that** warning.

Comment: add `console.log(DropZone)` in your render function - it's probably `undefined`

Comment: @ic3b3rg as you say, I did. but it rendered well. **exactly** the component

Answer (score 0):

this warning removed by eliminating `{...this.props}`. 
the problem was that `Custmized DropZone` Component gave props  `imported Child DropZone Component` that dosn't have.